# WAMP Server 3 - Lan Web Server

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, vhosts

Good day, I have Windows Server 2012 R2, I installed WAMP Server 3, on wamp settings I enabled the following
- Virtual host sub-menu
- Menu item: Online/Offline

when installing wamp a "my-site" folder was created, i created a index.html file in there with a

then i created a vhost using the GUI (localhost)

and the httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this

ServerName my-site.dev
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/my-site

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local

after this, i clicked on Put Online and disabled my windows firewall

from a different computer on the network i am trying to access to (http://29.8.14.2/my-site.dev) (IP of the windows server / folder) but i get the message

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /my-site.dev on this server.
Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at 29.8.14.2 Port 80"

could you please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I answered this over on the WAMPServer forum but I thought it may be relevant to have an answer here as well.

First you cannot use publically addressable IP Addresses for a local network. So your `29.8.14.xx` address range is probably causing some or all or these problems.

There are 3 address ranges provided for Private ip address ranges for Small, Medium and Large Internal networks and they are

```
RFC1918 name    IP address range               number of addresses
24-bit block    10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255      16,777,216
20-bit block    172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255     1,048,576
16-bit block    192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255      65,536
```

Pick one that suites your clients network size, current and potential.

Your next problem will be how to get all the PC's in this network to know where `mysite.dev` is in the network. If its only a few PC's then you can edit the HOSTS file on each PC and add an entry like this to each, I am assuming you go for the `16-bit block` address range.

```
192.168.1.2  mysite.dev
```

just like you did to the PC running WAMPServer, but pointing the domain name to the IP Address of the PC running WAMPServer and your site.

Alternatively, if your client has a local DNS Server and MANY PC's, then it would be much easier to add your site to his DNS Server and then every PC should know where to find `mysite.dev`